# Calling virtual function from static function

Tags: c++, winapi, static, virtual

**CASE**

My base class "Control" subclasses WinAPI button control:

```
hWndControl = CreateWindowEx
(
      0
    , L"BUTTON"
    , L"Button"
    , WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_OWNERDRAW | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
    , wndRc.left
    , wndRc.top
    , wndRc.right
    , wndRc.bottom
    , hWndParent
    , 0
    , hInstance
    , 0
);

void* p_this{reinterpret_cast<void*>(this)}; // avoiding C-style cast    
SetWindowSubclass
(
      hWndControl
    , Control::ControlProc
    , 0
    , reinterpret_cast<DWORD_PTR>(p_this)
)
```

As far as I know this requires me to define the callback as static (which I do).
Here is the callback sample for reference:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK Control::ControlProc
(
      HWND hWnd
    , UINT msg
    , WPARAM wParam
    , LPARAM lParam
    , UINT_PTR uIdSubclass
    , DWORD_PTR dwRefData
)
{
    //  RETRIEVE POINTER TO THIS CLASS OBJECT
    void* p_thisV{reinterpret_cast<void*>(dwRefData)}; // avoiding C-style cast
    Control* const p_this{reinterpret_cast<Control*>(p_thisV)};

    // PROCESS MESSAGES
    switch (msg)
    {
        //  DRAWING
        case MY_DRAWITEM: // custom message forwarding WM_DRAWITEM from main window
        {
            p_this->DrawControl();
        }
        break;

        ...
    }
    return DefSubclassProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

As far as here everything works fine if I do the drawing in the callback function, or in member function defined in the base class referenced in callback.

But I plan to inherit this base class for multiple different controls with different looks while using the same callback. So I thought I would create virtual functions called in specific points of the callback, which I can override in derived class with custom behavior for each derived class like so:

```
//  Base class header
class Control
{
    ...
    protected:
    virtual void DrawControl();
    ...
};

//  Derived class header
class CalendarItem : public Control
{
    ...
    protected:
    void DrawControl();
    ...
};

//  Derived class cpp
void CalendarItem::DrawControl()
{
    std::unique_ptr<DrawBg> drawBg = std::unique_ptr<DrawBg>(new DrawBg(Control::hWndControl));
    //  this is the actual drawing mechanism, works, not relevant
}
```

**PROBLEM**

I get exception in the callback function on line: `p_this->DrawControl();`

Exception text: p_this->**** was 0x75004D.

Can you please tell me how to fix this solution to work, or whether something like this is even possible?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Do you use multiple inheritance or virtual inheritance? If so, `reinterpret_cast` is obviously problematic.

Comment: @AlexGuteniev Not a problem if the pointer types before and after all the casts are the same type.

Comment: Aside: you can safely `reinterpret_cast` directly from any object pointer type to an integer type "large enough" like `DWORD_PTR` and back to the original pointer type. You don't need the intermediate `void*` values.

Comment: Sure not a problem if `this` is obtained form `Control` class. But it is not shown if `this` is obtained from `Control` class or not.

Comment: @AlexGuteniev when debuging I found interesting thing. The address of the pointer stays the same, but the address of internal class objects change.
When subclassing: 
0x0065f778 {hWndParent=0x0006055e {unused=0 } hWndControl=0x000904a4 {unused=0 } wndRc={LT(200, 200) RB(50, 50)  [-150 x -150]} }
In callback:
0x0065f778 {hWndParent=0x00650074 {unused=0 } hWndControl=0x00440078 {unused=??? } wndRc={LT(6684773, 7667809) RB(7602284, 49)  [917511 x -7667760]} }
Do you have any idea why? Especially the RECT wndRc gets totally broken.

Comment: @Xzsh4s575sf75 this mean that you pass pointer to temporary object in stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct solution was hinted at by RbMm - `this` pointer is on stack, we need heap pointer so that it stays in memory when the callback function runs (so current running function is already finished).

**The correct solution:**

Creating derived class object:

```
// provide base class pointer stored on heap
Derived* der = new Derived;
der->CreateInDerived(&(*der), ...); // "&(*der)" gets base class ptr from derived ptr
```

Derived class function:

```
void Derived::CreateInDerived(Base* ptr, ...)
{
    ptr->CreateInBase(ptr, ...);
}
```

Base class function:

```
void Base::CreateInBase(Base* ptr, ...)
{
    ...
    SetWindowSubclass
    (
          hWndControl
        , Control::ControlProc
        , 0
        , reinterpret_cast<DWORD_PTR>(ptr)
    )
    ...
}
```

**Explanation:**

The problem was not at all in the clash of virtual and static function, but in life length of transferred pointer. The pointer address was turned into a number in the function A, so that it can be given to callback function B through DWORD parameter.

When function B attempted to retrieve the pointer address back from the number, pointer defined in function A was alrady out of scope (and probably overwritten, since function A finished and released the memory).

Comment: There is nothing wrong with providing the subclass with a pointer to an object on the stack, provided the subclass is removed before the object is destroyed. If the object is copied, a new subclass is needed for the copy

Answer (score 0):

`ControlProc()` expects to receive a `Control*` pointer, not a `CalendarItem*` pointer, or any other derived class pointer. So, when casting `this`, you need to convert it to a valid `Control*` pointer *first*, then cast that as-is to `DWORD_PTR` for `SetWindowSubclass()`, and then in `ControlProc()` you can cast the `DWORD_PTR` back to `Control*` directly. You don't need to, and should not, cast to an intermediate `void*` at all.

```cpp
Control* p_this = this; // implicit conversion, no explicit cast needed
SetWindowSubclass
(
    hWndControl,
    Control::ControlProc,
    0,
    reinterpret_cast<DWORD_PTR>(p_this)
);
```

```cpp
LRESULT CALLBACK Control::ControlProc
(
    HWND hWnd,
    UINT msg,
    WPARAM wParam,
    LPARAM lParam,
    UINT_PTR uIdSubclass,
    DWORD_PTR dwRefData
)
{
    // RETRIEVE POINTER TO THIS CLASS OBJECT
    Control* const p_this = reinterpret_cast<Control*>(dwRefData);
    ...
    return DefSubclassProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: Hello Remy, thank you for answer, but I specificaly say in the first sentence that the code is in the base class, and that it subclasses WinAPI control, not another class. But I also tried and it doesn't work.